# Convert Text to Arabic

Tags: java, algorithm, validation, base64

**Problem statement :**

I want to convert this value to Arabic :

```
2K7Yp9mE2K8g2KfZhCDZhtmF2YTYp9mG
```

Unable to find a way to convert in into `base64`.

Please suggest

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Sharing what have you tried would be also good

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode("2K7Yp9mE2K8g2KfZhCDZhtmF2YTYp9mG");
    String output = new String(decoded);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

**Output:**

```
خالد ال نملان
```

Comment: Please tell the jar that you have used here

Comment: @AnkitJindal `import java.util.Base64;`.

Answer (score 0):

خالد ال نملان
Is this the expected output? 
From code:

```
    sun.misc.BASE64Decoder base64Decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    byte[] ddd = base64Decoder.decodeBuffer("2K7Yp9mE2K8g2KfZhCDZhtmF2YTYp9mG");
    String s = new String(ddd);
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Please tell the jar that you have used here

Comment: sun.misc.BASE64Decoder.jar. Use google to search it.